# Scanner device control in ios

Tags: ios

I want to control scanner device through my iPhone app. Probably, the scanner machine writes output in particular path(image folder), but i want change the path using my iPhone app. I went through TWAIN api and MFI (made for iPhone) program, but i want to use already developed one. Is there any company that provides library to access its scanner device?

https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/

http://www.twain.org/

I have worked with cctv camera(ip-camera), we can handle it by its ip-address. I am looking for something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can understand from your question, I do not believe there is a way to connect to a Scanner via the USB/Lightning port.

Some scanners nowadays either have the ability already or the option to allow for Wifi connection with the device and the scanner. But these require development kits from the manufacturers and may involve a license fee or NDA.

From memory Canon, Fujitsu and Epson have scanners with this sort of capability, but there is no unified way of connecting them and would have to be done through individual SDK's